# Is it possible to use custom hooks inside getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to reuse a code inside many `getServerSideProps` in many pages that I have.

Since React's way of reusing logic is by creating custom hooks, I created a custom hook.

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
    
    const customFunctionOfHook
    
    return {
        customFunctionOfHook
    }
}
```

Then I used it inside my `getServerSideProps`:

```
import useCustomHook from '../Hooks/CustomHook'

const getServerSideProps = () => {
    const { customFunctionOfHook } = useCustomHook()

    const result = customFunctionOHook() // Next.js complains that this is undefined

    return {
        props: { }
    }
}
```

So, can I use a custom hook inside `getServerSideProps`? If not, how can I reuse logic and code between multiple `getServerSideProps` functions?

Comment: *"Since React's way of reusing logic is by creating custom hooks, I created a custom hook."* That's not always true. A hook is mainly for a specific use case. You could use a normal function. `getServerSideProps` is not a React component, so it doesn't make sens to have a hook there.

Comment: @yousoumar, a React hook is basically a simple JS function. It just starts with `use` by convention. Otherwise, it's a normal JS function. You mean I should remove the `use` from its beginning?

Comment: Saying that "a React hook is basically a simple JS function" is like saying `useState` is the same as `setTimout`. Yes, they are functions but meant for different things. If you want to use it in `getServerSideProps`, you cannot use anything React-specific in it, like calling `useEffect`. And yes, remove `use` so you don't mislead future colleagues.